# PNG loses transparency when converting from a Bitmap

Tags: delphi, png, imaging

I load a png file into a TPNGImage, and then display it in a TImage. No problem. Then I create a TBitmap and assign it to the TPNGImage, and display it in a TImage. No problem.

Then I create a second TPNGImage and assign it to the TBitmap. In this case if I display it in a TImage, it has lost it's transparency. If I set the TBitmap.Transparent to True, before assigning to the PNGImage, the PNGImage is mostly transparent, but there is a small area where the transparency was lost, showing in black.

```
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  PngImage: TPNGImage;
  PngImage2: TPNGImage;
begin
  PngImage := TPNGImage.Create;
  try
    PngImage.LoadFromFile(FILE_NAME);
    Image1.Picture.Assign(PngImage);

    Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      Bmp.Assign(PngImage);
      Image2.Picture.Assign(Bmp);

      PngImage2 := TPNGImage.Create;
      try
        //Bmp.Transparent := True;
        PngImage2.Assign(Bmp);
        Image3.Picture.Assign(PngImage2);
      finally
        PngImage2.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Bmp.Free;
    end;
  finally
    PngImage.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Result without setting Bitmap.Transparent to True:

[image]

Result when I set Bitmap.Transparent to True: There is a small bit of black in the Image

[image]

How can I assign the PNGImage to the Bitmap without losing *any* transparency?

Comment: Probably no easy way out of this with the built in code. You are going to need to write your own code to transfer from PNG to 32bpp bitmap, or find a library that does this

Comment: This is not teivial. A simple Assign wont work. And even if you convert the png to a 32 bit bitmap with alpha you can not assign it to a TImage and you will need to custom draw it. The real queation is why mess with a TBitmap when you have the TPngImage already and can assign that to the TImage?

Comment: `TransparentColor` is for non-transparent bitmaps, it has no relevance to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm what @SertacAkyuz said in the comments. There is no problem with:

```
Bmp.Assign(PngImage);
```

The result is a 32bit image that preserves the alpha channel. The problem is with

```
PngImage2.Assign(Bmp);
```

Where the alpha is lost.

I found this library to help with the conversion:

https://github.com/graphics32/GR32PNG

Answer (score 1):

I can only speculate... But PNGs support partial transparency, and 24-bits bitmaps don't. And since the leftover "black" pixels aren't black (they are $000101), I suspect those pixels are semi-transparent in the original png. That, or some antialising effect was applied when converting to bitmap. But I believe semi-transparency is more likely.

I never really worked with 32 bits bitmap, but maybe they could be used to preserve the transparency. (They do have an alpha channel...).  But I suspect it might be more tricky than just Bitmap.Assign.

Comment: Actual case is that the bitmap in question is 32bit and have the alpha channel. But the pngimage does not support transfer of alpha from assignment of a bitmap.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: What happens when you save a 32bit bitmap to file? Does it remove the alpha channel? I did so, and then tried to open the image in Gimp. It does not show an alpha channel.

Comment: @Rael - I did the same test before commenting, just after `Bmp.Assign(PngImage);` I inserted `Bmp.SaveToFile()`. Alpha remains intact, originally checked with XnView but now I also checked with Gimp.

Comment: XnView has this setting "Use Alpha Channel". I can use that to view the alpha channel. Is there something equivalent in Gimp? In Gimp it looks like there is no alpha channel...

Comment: The version I use (2.6.12) have a "channels dialog". Additionally in preferences->display there are the checkerboard settings.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, I'm a bit confused. `"Alpha remains intact"`: so the pngimage *does* support transfer of alpha from assignment of a bitmap? or you meant that the alpha of the bitmap remains unchanged?

Comment: @kobik - No, I meant the other way around... when a bitmap is assigned a pngimage, the bitmap preserves the alpha channel of the png. "Preserve" is not the correct term here probably though, perhaps transfer would be better. . Pngimage does not support alpha channel transfer from assignment of anything other than another pngimage.